# XCode 13 SwiftUI "Cannot preview in this file - Message send failure for update"

Tags: xcode, swiftui

whilst working on an existing XCode project, the simulator began consistently crashing. The preview window will not show the current file, with a red banner and the below error:

```
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for update
==================================
|  MessageError: Connection interrupted
```

I have tried:

- Restarting XCode
- Restarting the Mac
- Cleaning the project
- Deleting DerivedData
- Deleting the local copy and cloning from GitHub

Nothing seems to be working. Does anyone know how to resolve this? It was working fine previously, seems to have broken at random.

I am using XCode 13.2.1

Edit: This is only affecting this app. Other projects still work fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to fix this by wrapping the ContentView() call in the preview in a ZStack. This is a known bug caused by @FocusState when used in a top-level view that the preview window is rendering.

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ZStack {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: https://developers.apple.com/forums/thread/681571?answerId=690251022#690251022

Comment: I haven't consistently been able to use previews since launch. The fact that this workaround worked for me is ridiculous.

Comment: SwiftUI is already several years old, and such ridiculous things never cease to amaze me (this solution wokred for me)

Answer (score 8):

Quit XCode and run this terminal command:

```
xcrun simctl --set previews delete all
```

Then open your project, build it and try reloading the preview.

Comment: No luck sadly. Still says connection interrupted. Oddly enough it's only affecting this project; if I create a new one the preview works fine

Comment: Your crash logs for the preview are stored at `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`, maybe you can at least find the problem there

Comment: I tied this solution on Xcode 14, it did't work on it

Comment: Thank you! I had to reselect command line tools for some reason but this worked!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I discovered that I had an unfortunate directory name collision - specifically, I had both

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator\ Devices
```

and

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews/Simulator%20Devices
```

Deleting both of them solved the problem (in my case, the app widget worked in the simulator, but in the Xcode canvas, it would not launch.

Comment: It didn't work. **Xcode 14.2**  just recreated the directories.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Derived Data location in XCode to "Default" appears to fix a related issue:

```
MessageSendFailure: Message send failure for update

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError
|  
|  LoadingError: failed to load library at path...
```

[XCode preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9pWO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing **Derived data** and **Archives** to *"Default"* worked for me.

I was using an external SSD to store the file and I had a custom path.
After changing it in Settings/Locations it worked

Answer (score 0):

1. close Xcode and simulator.
2. Delete Previews inside (but not the Preview folder itself)

/Users/me.myself/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Previews
run

3. killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

4.Restart Xcode

Answer (score -3):

The error you're facing with the SwiftUI preview is not uncommon, and it can be frustrating, especially when it appears seemingly out of the blue. Given what you've already tried, here are some more potential solutions and troubleshooting steps to consider:

1. **Check for SwiftUI Compatibility**:

   - Ensure all components in your SwiftUI code are compatible and don't contain any unsupported or beta features.
   - Sometimes the use of specific SwiftUI components or certain combinations might cause the preview to fail.
2. **Update Xcode**:

   - Even though you mentioned your Xcode version, there might have been updates or patches after 13.2.1. Check the App Store for any updates.
3. **Check for Error in Code**:

   - Sometimes the preview won't load due to a logical error in your code that prevents it from rendering. Even if the code compiles, there might be something SwiftUI doesn't like.
4. **Inspect Console**:

   - Look at the console log for more detailed error messages. The error message displayed in the preview pane is often very generic. The console might have more actionable information.
5. **Try a Different Simulator**:

   - Instead of using the default simulator, try previewing with a different device type.
6. **Inspect Dependencies**:

   - If you have any third-party libraries or Swift packages, ensure they're up-to-date and compatible with the version of SwiftUI you're using.
7. **Canvas Debugger**:

   - In Xcode's canvas, there's a "Diagnostics" option (typically a small exclamation mark in a triangle). Click on that to get more detailed error messages, if available.
8. **Test on a Real Device**:

   - Even if the preview doesn't work, the app might run just fine on a real device. Try that to see if there's any runtime error or issue you can pinpoint.
9. **Create a New SwiftUI View**:

   - As a test, create a new SwiftUI view and see if you can preview that. If you can, slowly add components from the problematic view to see if you can identify a specific piece of code causing the issue.
10. **SwiftUI Environment**:

- Ensure you aren't modifying any environment values (like `\.managedObjectContext`) in a way that could disrupt the preview.

11. **Check Provisioning Profiles**:

- Sometimes, weird Xcode behaviors have been tied to provisioning profile issues. Ensure your profiles are correctly set up.

12. **Xcode Preferences**:

- Go to `Xcode` > `Preferences` > `Locations`, and ensure that the Command Line Tools setting is correctly set to your Xcode version.

13. **Update macOS**:

- If there's an update available for macOS, consider updating. Sometimes, compatibility issues between Xcode and macOS can cause such problems.

If you've tried everything and the issue persists, it might be helpful to reach out to Apple's Developer Support or the developer forums for more specialized help. Remember, sometimes, it might be an Xcode bug that needs an official patch or update.